# not returning 0 if value is NULL

Tags: postgresql

Everything works as intended, but function should return 0 if value is NULL. Currently it returns nothing (see problem at the end of the post).

How could I make to return 0 if no order is found?

'orders' Table

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    code INT NOT NULL, 
    service_id INT NOT NULL, 
    status CHARACTER VARYING(50), 
    creation TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    status_date TIMESTAMP,
    created_user INT
    );
```

Records

```
INSERT INTO orders 
(id, code, service_id, status, creation, status_date, created_user) 
VALUES 
(100,2394,558151,'Requested','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2394,558151,'Fulfilled','2018-06-16 11:12','2018-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2394,558151,'Requested','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2395,558152,'Requested','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2396,558153,'Requested','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1),
(100,2394,558151,'Requested','2019-06-16 11:12','2019-06-18 14:08',1);
```

Testing Statement

```
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation) AS year, 
                        orders.code, 
                        COUNT(orders.code) 
                FROM orders
                WHERE status = 'Requested' AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation) = 2019 AND orders.code = 2394
                GROUP BY year, orders.code
                ORDER BY year ASC
```

Returns

> ```
> year | code | count
> :--- | ---: | ----:
> 2019 | 2394 |     3
> ```

## Function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
yearly_orders(inyear numeric DEFAULT 0, incode INT DEFAULT 0) 
RETURNS TABLE (retyear numeric, retcode bigint, retcout bigint) AS 
$$
DECLARE
    retcount int DEFAULT 0;
    retcode int DEFAULT 0;
    retyear numeric DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM creation) as numeric), 
                        CAST(orders.code as bigint), 
                        COUNT(orders.code)
                FROM orders
                WHERE status = 'Requested' 
                AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation) = inyear 
                AND orders.code = incode
                GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM creation), orders.code
                ORDER BY retyear ASC;

END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Executing Function

```
select * from yearly_orders(2019, 1194);
```

#### Returns <-- **PROBLEM**

> ```
> retyear | retcode | retcout
> ------: | ------: | ------:
>         |         |
> ```

SHOULD RETURN

> ```
> retyear | retcode | retcout
> ------: | ------: | ------:
>  0       |     0    |    0
> ```

## db<>fiddle

The db<>fiddle to try this out can be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=b9ce1d3f853272ce08e9f75e1eb884b6).

The code was made by user:15356 ([Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/290693/how-to-make-a-function-in-postgresql-with-two-parameters-to-return-count-from-co/290712#290712?newreg=e6cd015249344d0f91ccf82ac5eb734b))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wanting `GROUP BY` and the `COUNT` aggregate to return a row with a zero value when there are otherwise no rows to return - `GROUP`ing does not work like that. It combines what rows would have been returned if `GROUP BY` was not present, so no rows in that case.

You could add a second `SELECT`, combined with `UNION ALL`, that returns one row containing `inyear, incode, 0` if there are zero matching rows (counted by sub-select). If there are rows this part returns nothing, if there are no matches it returns a row indicating that. Note that this may be quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually tricky, you could raise a message like in the example

> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
> yearly_orders(inyear numeric DEFAULT 0, incode INT DEFAULT 0) 
> RETURNS TABLE (retyear numeric, retcode bigint, retcout bigint) AS 
> $$
> DECLARE
>     retcount int DEFAULT 0;
>     retcode int DEFAULT 0;
>     retyear numeric DEFAULT 0;
>     row_cnt int DEFAULT 0;
> BEGIN
>     RETURN QUERY SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(year FROM creation) as numeric) , 
>                         CAST(orders.code as bigint) , 
>                         COUNT(orders.code) 
>                 FROM orders
>                 WHERE status = 'Requested' 
>                 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM creation) = inyear 
>                 AND orders.code = incode
>                 GROUP BY EXTRACT(year FROM creation), orders.code
>                 ORDER BY retyear ASC;
>     GET DIAGNOSTICS row_cnt = ROW_COUNT;
>
>    IF row_cnt =  0 THEN
>       RAISE SQLSTATE '45000'   -- 5 ASCII chars
>       USING MESSAGE = format('No orders found for year %s.',inyear);
>    END IF;
>
> END;
> $$
> LANGUAGE plpgsql;
> ```

> ```
> select * from yearly_orders(2020, 2394);
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  No orders found for year 2020.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function yearly_orders(numeric,integer) line 20 at RAISE
> ```

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3a5757a1bf5ecc4bc28038d794d066ad)*

Comment: Because I really didn't need all that code, deleting GROUP BY (and a couple of lines more) made it work. But I really appreciate your answer, I'm pretty sure I'll use it in the next task. Plus seeing more examples of functional code helps me a lot. Thank you so much!